# SSIS not logging error while source data has null and destination column is not nullable with OLDEDBDestination Task

Tags: error-handling, ssis, oledbdestination

Getting one weird issue with my one SSIS Package.

I have a column in source (e.g. column FirstName) which is null. and in OLEDBDestination the Destination column(Destination.FirstName) which is mapped with above source column(Source.FirstName) is not nullable.

Now when the DFT is getting executed, it doesnt throw any error and keeps running. when i check in sql server the process gets suspended.

the SSIS doesnt throw any error for this.

any idea what is the solution for this other than keeping both column's nullable option same?

Answer (score 0):

Check that all your FailPackageOnError properties are set to "True".

Also check for any OnError handlers that catch the error and prevent it from being raised.